# need a suggestion for platform/plugin for online store to serve as a base for many sellers

Tags: wordpress, drupal, e-commerce, store

I building a website to act as an online store, but I'm not selling anything. I want to give the possibility of sellers to register (manual process) and then put their items on the store catalogue (all mixed up).
I have experience with Drupal and Wordpress, and I know both have several e-commerce plugins, but I'm kind of lost reading about so many different ones and not knowing if they can do this or not.
Anyone can give me an hint?

Comment: There is no need of "first/second... question" remarks. Please also avoid "thank you notes", instead up-vote good answers and accept the best/most useful one.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend those CMS/Blogs.. Try Magento which is free also - One of Magento's advanced features allows for management of multiple websites and stores within one installation.

Comment: maybe my question was not clear. I do not need multiple websites or stores. only one website, one store, one catalog, but with multiple sellers accounts that can add their own products. 
thanks for the suggestion though, I will check magento

Comment: There's no need to add a signature to the end of your answer. It gets added automatically by StackOverflow. Also, unless your website is an example of what you're illustrating in the answer, don't include it as part of your answer.